# Python to detect and roate pages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I know this might not be possible but I wanted to ask anyways. I know within python there are several different packages to modify PDF's such as PyPDF2, PDFminer, PyMuPDF, etc. However I am curious if anyone knows of a way to detect if a page is rotated 180 degrees in the wrong direction, i.e. a scanned page is upside and needs to be rotated. I know you can rotate indivudal pages or several pages but I am wanting to write a script to detect pages that are upside and roate? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.